# How to determine when all network calls are done?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, okhttp

I have a fragment which displays a progress bar `onViewCreated`. Then, several network calls are performed asynchronously on a **REST Api** through **Okhttp**. Network calls are run in the background through Okhttp's `enqueue` method.

```
//several calls similar to this
okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            //Response JSOn is parsed here
            //then inserted to SQLite
        }
    });
```

In each callback, the response **JSON** is parsed and inserted into an **SQLite** table for offline data access. Images are also to be retrieved and cached for offline usage.

How can I tell when `All` threads are done, from the **main thread**, to dismiss the progress bar and notify the user?

Comment: ... you count the started threads and count the finished threads?

Comment: @slowy Is it reliable to do it that way?

Comment: if you implement it "safely", yeah - it's also the easiest solution, but might be too easy... you should consider informing yourself about thread management. I'm not sure how it works on android, but in general, it's not a best practice to just create threads without having certain amount of control over them, it can be very easy to crash an app...

Comment: @slowy If I knew how to implement it safely or had the time to dive deeply into thread management, i wouldn't have posted a question on Stackoverflow :) Please provide more info, or a reference.

Comment: That's not how it works, son. If you ask a question and even state, that you do not have the time to figure it out yourself, or even worse, not _want to learn, how stuff works_, why would you assume, the reader of that question will invest _his_ time to answer? That's quite a demand, and to be honest: rude as hell: You just told me that _my_ time is less worth than yours. I really enjoy helping people and see that they can learn from my experience and knowledge, because there's people who did the same for me - but I'm not going to do your work. http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @slowy First, my comment was not meant to be rude in any sort. Stackoverflow is a place for sharing knowledge and experience. I can certainly use advice from more experienced developers who can direct me to best practice based on their experience. I don't want anyone doing my work, I want to learn and be guided. I've already read lots of docs regarding this issue: reactive programming, promises, Java Future, etc. What's the best approach, in your experience?